# automated system is not letting ask a valid question

Tags: support, bug, asking-questions

I am trying to post a question
**Subject** : What is the meaning of the git option u?

**Body** :

> what does the -u option does in following git command
>
> git push -u origin master
>
> and how is it different from
>
> git push origin master

I get following error

This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Comment: This isn't why your question couldn't be posted, but we're you to post it, it would possibly be closed as a duplicate of [What exactly does the “u” do? “git push -u origin master” vs “git push origin master”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5697750/1364007) or similar.

Comment: Please also refer to this resource for asking questions on Stack Overflow: [stack-overflow-question-checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist). It's written by a guy who's answered a good number of questions.

Comment: Were you literally using quote formatting for the question or did you just use it here to make it clear which part was the question on main?

Answer (score 5):

That is not a "valid" question. If the way you've presented it here accurately reflects the way you tried to submit it to Stack Overflow, then it's no wonder that the system rejected it. It doesn't even come close to meeting our quality standards.

For starters, you failed to use any sort of formatting to indicate the commands being literally typed in the terminal. Second, you didn't use proper grammar—there are no capital letters, no punctuation, confusing sentence structure, etc. Third, you included no background information or context. There's no evidence of research effort. You didn't tell us why you're asking this question, what you're trying to do, and/or what you were able to discover in attempting to answer the question yourself. Did you read a man page? Search Google? What did you find? What part did you not understand?

In short: **the question is hard to read, hard to understand, and contains no evidence of research effort**. The automated block is working correctly in this case. A question like this should never be allowed to be submitted on this site. And even if you did manage to trick the automatic quality filter, a question like this would inevitably be downvoted and closed, so it wouldn't do you much good to try and force it through.

Here's a version of your proposed question that addresses the first and second problems (formatting and grammar):

> What effect does the `-u` option have in the `git push` command?
>
> More concretely, I want to know how the following command:
>
> ```
> git push -u origin master
> ```
>
> is different from this command:
>
> ```
> git push origin master
> ```

This still isn't a great question because it still doesn't resolve the third problem (lack of context and no evidence of research effort), but it'll probably go through the automated quality filter.